# Tornado python - how to sort queries to mongoDB using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, tornado, pymongo

Would like to sort a simple query, but not sure how this works with "gen.task", as it takes a method as arg1 and param as arg2.

This works more than fine :

```
response, error = yield gen.Task(db.client().collection.find, {"user_id":user_id})
if response:
    #blablabla
```

But then how do I give it the sort()?

UPDATE : This now throws a 'callback must be callable' error. Which seems to be some other issue with Tornado now.

```
def findsort(self, find, callback):
    return callback(db.client().collection.find(find).sort({"myfield":1}))

@gen.engine
def anotherfunction(self):
    response, error = yield gen.Task(self.findsort, {"user_id":user_id})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `asyncmongo`, it works perfectly with `gen`.

After juggling you will get something like this:

```
DB = asyncmongo.Client()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        result, error = yield gen.Task(DB.collection.find, {}, limit=50, sort=[('myfield', 1)])
```

And about 'callback must be callable'.. When working with `gen` - always describe +1 argument in functions, which is called by `gen.Task`.

```
def findsort(self, find, params, callback): #here we recieve self + 3 args, if we remove params - callback will contain {"user_id":user_id} 
    return callback(db.client().collection.find(find).sort({"myfield":1}))

@gen.engine
def anotherfunction(self):
    response, error = yield gen.Task(self.findsort, {"user_id":user_id}) #we see 2 args, but it passes 3 args to findsort
```

Comment: Great! I was looking for the "limit=50, sort=[('myfield', 1)]" part...of course it was just in the main docs on GitHub. Eh...thanks for the explanation for gen.Task + its callback, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with gen.Task but maybe you could try:

```
@gen.engine
def anotherfunction(self):

    def findsort(find):
         return db.client().collection.find(find).sort({"myfield":1})

    response, error = yield gen.Task(findsort, {"user_id":user_id})
```

Comment: Just updated the question - running into something else now "TypeError: callback must be callable"

Comment: same error pops up - for some reason it's expecting a callback. Thing is that mongo *does* have meta query operators, just can't figure out how to use it http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24orderby

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to make db calls to mongo db asynchronous. By default pymongo is blocking but there is a separate branch called motor which makes it possible to have async queries.

See http://emptysquare.net/blog/introducing-motor-an-asynchronous-mongodb-driver-for-python-and-tornado/ for more details.

It supports the tornado.gen generator pattern too.

Comment: I'm also using the @asynchronous decorator which makes it async. It's just about getting the sorting param in there.

Comment: @L-R Adding asynchronous decorator makes the view function asynchronous but you don't get the benefit if your code isn't async. For example if you have a `time.sleep(x)` inside your view function, it is still blocking. [IOLoop.add_timout](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout) OTOH is is a non-blocking alternative to `time.sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [asyncmongo](https://github.com/bitly/asyncmongo/), an async implemntation of pymongo.
`gen.Task` requires the function to have a `callback` parameter.

Comment: `Asyncmongo` provides `callback` argument to `gen`, so no errors will happen.